# Accessing a control - Missing a using directive or assembly reference

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

I am using WPF application in C# and I want at the beginning to draw a triangle.

This is the error that appears when I run the program:

> 'WpfApplication1.mainWindow' does not contain a definition for
>   'mainViewport' and no extension method for 'mainViewport' accepting a
>   first argument of type 'WpfApplication1.mainWindow' could be found.
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my XAML page:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="WPF 3D Chart" Height="455" Width="689">
    <Grid>
        <Viewport3D Name="mainViewport" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Viewport3D.Camera>
                <PerspectiveCamera 
  FarPlaneDistance="100"
  LookDirection="-11,-10,-9"
  UpDirection="0,1,0"
  NearPlaneDistance="1" 
  Position="11,10,9" 
  FieldOfView="70" />
            </Viewport3D.Camera>
            <ModelVisual3D>
                <ModelVisual3D.Content>
                    <DirectionalLight 
    Color="White" 
    Direction="-2,-3,-1" />
                </ModelVisual3D.Content>
            </ModelVisual3D>
        </Viewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and this is my code: (the error appears on the last line of my code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;


namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D point0 = new Point3D(-0.5, 0, 0);
            System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D point1 = new Point3D(0.5, 0.5, 0.3);
            System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3D point2 = new Point3D(0, 0.5, 0);


            System.Windows.Media.Media3D.MeshGeometry3D triangleMesh = new MeshGeometry3D();

            triangleMesh.Positions.Add(point0);
            triangleMesh.Positions.Add(point1);
            triangleMesh.Positions.Add(point2);

            int n0 = 0;
            int n1 = 1;
            int n2 = 2;

            triangleMesh.TriangleIndices.Add(n0);
            triangleMesh.TriangleIndices.Add(n1);
            triangleMesh.TriangleIndices.Add(n2);

            System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D norm = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);
            triangleMesh.Normals.Add(norm);
            triangleMesh.Normals.Add(norm);
            triangleMesh.Normals.Add(norm);

            System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Material frontMaterial = new DiffuseMaterial(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));

            System.Windows.Media.Media3D.GeometryModel3D triangleModel = new GeometryModel3D(triangleMesh, frontMaterial);

            triangleModel.Transform = new Transform3DGroup();

            System.Windows.Media.Media3D.ModelVisual3D visualModel = new ModelVisual3D();
            visualModel.Content = triangleModel;

            this.mainViewport.Children.Add(visualModel); //here appears the error         
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't access the Viewport3D control this way because it is inside a Grid. You need to access it via the Grid's children controls. use the FindName() method.

Comment: @ShaiAharoni completely not true. Too bad I cannot downvote comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are refering to the Viewport in the constructor. At that moment in time the Viewport has not been created yet.

Use the Loaded event handler of the Window like this

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
```

Do NOT leave the constructor empty! There is an important call in there! The InitializeComponent loads the UI of the Window.

As far as I can see you removed that call in your code and that causes the code to break as well. Use the Loaded handler, that is what is for.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I get the bigger idea of what you are trying to say. if understood well, you mean to leave the constructor "Public Main Window () {}" empty and to write my code somewhere else? if so, what do you mean by the loaded event handler of the window?

Comment: You are right, at the beginning I didn't understant what the InitializeComponent() was for so I deleted it ! thanks a lot, it works now !

Answer (score 1):

Your XAML creates a class named `WPFChart.Window1` while your code modifies a class called `WpfApplication1.MainWindow`. I don't know which one is right, but you need to change one of them so they match.

Comment: thanks, you are right ! I just changed it and no errors appear now. But the program still can't run, it says: "no source available - no symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed". any ideas how to fix that?